# pre-activation batch normalization in modern neural nets

Tags: neural-networks

Some of the more modern neural network architectures (Densenets, for example) use pre-activation batch normalization i.e batch normalization -> activation -> Convolution rather than the usual Convolution -> batch normalization -> activation.

The resulting network has the same number of parameters but most of the papers report that pre-activation in these networks is better. I am struggling to figure out why this is the case. Is there any intuitive or principled reasoning behind it?

Comment: Can you share citations of articles that find pre-activation normalized networks are better than post-activation normalized networks? I would be interested to read about them, and I wonder if the authors make passing mention of this phenomenon, perhaps in an appendix or other materials.

Comment: @Syrocax: I found this nice blog post discussing it: https://learningstracker.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/pre-activation-in-neural-networks/

Answer (score 1):

A convolutional unit of the form BN-ReLU-conv is convenient since it applies the batchnorm immediately after summation with the skip connection.

The original form (conv-BN-ReLu) allows the summation to spoil the normalization contributed by batchnorm. Additionally, the original form places a non-linear activation after the summation and before the next skip connection. This impedes the gradient flow towards earlier layers.